# awk command issue

Tags: awk

I am facing problem when trying to substitute the first line of a text file using `awk` command in Unix.

I am using this syntax:

```
awk '{ (FS=OFS=""); if($19=="2") sub($88,"4");print $0 }' input.txt>output.txt
```

this command is not editing the first line of the text file. what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's hard to understand what you are trying to do without an example of your input and expected output (in particular, `sub($88,"4")` looks dubious - the first argument of `sub` should be a regular expression).*

However, assuming you want an empty `FS` to be applied to the first record (line) of your input, then you need to set it *before* the first record is parsed - using a `BEGIN` rule. For example, compare

```
$ printf '123\n456\n' | awk '{FS=OFS=""; print $2}'

5
```

versus

```
$ printf '123\n456\n' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {print $2}'
2
5
```